# Verilog Synthesis Takes Too Long

Tags: verilog, digital, xilinx-ise

I am writing a synthesizable module in Verilog in the Xilinx ISE. Part of it is creating a 256x128x1 array with 1 bit in each of its cells and filling this array 1 bit at a time on every rising clock edge.

I've decided to ignore any for and while loops when filling it to reduce synthesis time. However, it still takes a lot of time to synthesize (I've let it run for 30 mins now and it still hasn't stopped). Is it normal to take a lot of time when it needs to create so much memory cells (32767) in the design?

Comment: with* not which (1st word 2nd line)

Comment: Synthesis tools unroll loops, and are usually pretty good at simplifying equalivent logic, so it is likely not the source of your problem. What FPGA are you synthesizing to, how big is your design and how power is the machine you are using for ise? All these are important factors in synthesis time

Comment: @thatguyoverthere: This should not take that long. One reason the synthesis tool takes a long time is when your clock frequency is very tight compared to the combinational logic. I would test it for a smaller size array first. If you post your code, we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large "array" with some seq/comb. logic, the synthesis just need more time to work on mapping and optimization, also the interconnection between 256x128x1 regs is not simple, and these connection is not free!
A another approach is to use memory library from vendor to reduce the synthesis time, however you might change your algorithm to fit into the new memory model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can re-organize your code to make BlockRAM memory with 256 elements, and each element is 128 bits wide. You can design a 128 bits wide shift register, and shift in 1 bit at every rising clock. And when you received the 128 beats of data, write it in the BlockRAM. This design will use the BlockRAM resources better than the original 32767x1 version.

However considering your lone run-time, does it happen at synthesis stage or PAR stage? It is not likely 32767x1 bits BlockRAM will cause the long run-time problem.